# AJAX wrapper for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a convenience method for my Ajax calls as it is used extensively in the project.

As of now a typical call in the project looks like this.

```
$.post(
  "url",
  {
    param1: value1,
    param2: value2
  },
  function (data) {}
);
```

This call is repeated multiple times in the project with different parameters so I would like to be able to create a function to which I can pass the parameters and it will handle the entire Ajax call without me having to write the code every time.
Expected Output:

```
var data= {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
do_ajax_request(data);
```

The function `do_ajax_request` in turn contains the actual Ajax code which makes the actual request and handles the result.
If possible I would also like for it to return a callback in case I need to perform any extra operations, would a promise work for that?
This would be a global function so I can access it from any JavaScript file.

Comment: So just return the Ajax object `function do_ajax_request (data) { return $.post("url", data); }` and you can do what ever with the done, fail, always.

Comment: So you want to write a wrapper for an `$.post` which is itself a wrapper for calls via `XMLHttpRequest`. Theres nothing inherently wrong with it (I have worked on at least one project which does exactly that), but be aware that its going to be hard to "makes the actual request and handles the result" for every possible case.

Comment: @epascarello I never tried that, seems like it could work, will give it a try.

Comment: @Jamiec does not sound very good but using it for very basic generic requests to increase productivity.

Comment: @JudeFernandes Im really not sure how much of an increase in productivity you'd get. Where I have used it the "generic" stuff it does is to show/hide a loading overlay/message. But I essentially do exactly as epascarello says and return the `$.post` so I can deal with the result in situ. You cant possibly deal with every response in a generic way.

Comment: @Jamiec trying to abstract basic CRUD operations which always take in a set of variables as input and return a response as output which is handled the same way on multiple pages.

Comment: @Jamiec Lets say you have 20 calls to same endpoint. You either 1) hard code the stuff in multiple lines of exact call, 2) You use variables so you can at least make change in one place, 3) write a wrapper that simplifies it. If you do 1, copy and paste code is a BAD idea. Make a change, 20 places. #2 has same issue if you need to alter something not in a variable, and 3, you make change at one place. Basic idea of simplified code that is shared. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @epascarello I agree 100%. I guess ive never had that usecase. I have 20 calls to different endpoints, but there is some shared functionality (just not what to pass and how to deal with the response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many complicated answers for something jQuery supports out of the box. Turning my comment to an answer.

You are basically just coding a wrapper for a wrapper so you do no have to recode some basic lines. No harm in that since it is easy to make the change in one place vs many.

So defined your function and just return the Ajax object that jQuery has. You can than use the done, fail, always methods.

```
function do_ajax_request (data) { 
  return $.post("url", data); 
}

do_ajax_request({"foo":"bar"})
  .done( function(){})
  .fail(function(){})

do_ajax_request({"foo":"bar"})
  .done( function(){})
  .fail(function(){})
```

If you want to have common code inside, you can do that too, basic idea for an error handler...

```
function do_ajax_request (data) { 
  var xhr = $.post("url", data);
  xhr.fail(function () {
    console.log(arguments)
  });
  return xhr;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, except when you start passing `url` to `do_ajax_request` as a parameter. Then you've just reinvented the wheel (That's a comment to the OP, not a criticism of this answer which clear does not do that!)

Comment: This is brilliant.I never knew how much I needed this.

Comment: @Jamiec Well if that is the case, than maybe this is bad and than I would look at using the jQuery Ajax methods to add common things to handle errors and setup. But in the end it is basic idea on how to simplify code. One solution never meets every possible case.  If it would, we might not really have jobs.

Comment: It turned out to be as simple as that, thank you @epascarello

Answer (score 2):

I have written several jQuery plug-ins for use in my projects, and have brought along my ajax call method in nearly everyone.  Here is a snippet of it from one of my projects.  Enjoy!

Method Signature:

- obj = An object you want to pass to the ajax call in the data parameter.  Pass null if not needed.
- method = ajax methods:  POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, etc.  Default is GET.
- endPoint = Url to call.
- returnType = html, json, text, etc.
- success = callback method when the call is successful.
- beforesend = method to call before the send.  This is useful when you need to set headers before a call.
- failure = callback method when the call is unsuccessul.

```
var _api = {
        call: function (obj, method, endPoint, returnType, success, beforesend, failure) {
            obj = obj === null || undefined ? {} : obj;
            $.ajax({
                method: method || 'GET',
                data: !$.isEmptyObject(obj) ? JSON.stringify(obj) : null,
                contentType: function () {
                    switch (returnType) {
                        case 'json':
                            return 'application/json';
                        case 'text':
                            return 'text/plain';
                        case 'buffer':
                            return 'arraybuffer';
                        case 'html':
                        default:
                            return 'text/html';
                    }
                }(returnType === 'json' ? 'application/json; charset=utf-8' : ''),
                url: endPoint,
                dataType: returnType,
                beforeSend: function (xhr, obj) {
                    if (beforesend) {
                        beforesend(xhr, obj);
                    } else {
                        _api.showLoader();
                    }
                }
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (success) success(data)
            }).fail(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (failure) failure()
            }).always(function () {
                // Implement code here that you want to run whenever the call is complete regardless of success or failure.
            });

        }
}
```

Comment: Very outdated callback method - use promises instead.

Comment: Would this allow me to also handle the callbacks on the page the call is being made from?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Callbacks passed in this manner are byref.

Comment: @JudeFernandes jQuery is moving away from the success, error, and complete in favor of the done, success, failure way. This code would work since it is the classical callback idea, but is a bit limited in what you can do.

Comment: @epascarello this is an easy upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a prototype to with a constructor to handle the input - make the request and handle the response:

```
ajax.requests = function ( data ) {
    this.data = data;
    return this.doRequest();
};

ajax.requests.prototype = {

    doRequest : function () {
        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            data: _this.data
        }).done(function(data) {
            Handle response and return!
        });
    }

};

// USAGE

var response = new ajax.requests( yourData );
```

Answer (score 1):

By *returning* the `$.post`, you can use a callback like [`.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), chain them together with [`.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), etc.

```
function do_ajax_request(data) {
    return $.post( ... );  //RETURN the object
}

var myData = { ... };
do_ajax_request(myData).done(function(result) {
    console.log("AJAX complete: " + result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Santi, that turned out to be the simplest and easiest way to do it, unfortunately stack overflow lets me select only 1 as the correct answer and  @epascarello came first.

Comment: @JudeFernandes No worries, his answer was a bit more detailed as well. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just another take on this that maybe you hadn't considered. Rather than trying to wrap what is essentially already a wrapper, consider encapsulating your common functionality, like handling errors and dealing with results and using this when executing an ajax request with the existing jQuery ajax wrapper(s)

```
function handleError(e){
   // your common error handling
}

function handleResult(result){
   // your common result handling
}

// then every time you execute a request, use your shared functionality
$.post(url, data)
   .fail(handleError)
   .done(handleResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code below, you'd need to import config object or declare on top of the functions.

I made two versions for POST and GET respectively

```
function getJSON(param, absoluteRestUrl = '') {
    if (!absoluteRestUrl) {
        absoluteRestUrl = config.adminRestEndpoint; // defaultUrl
    }
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let res = null;
        res = await $.getJSON(absoluteRestUrl, param);
        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
    });
}

function postJSON(param, absoluteRestUrl = '') {
    if (!absoluteRestUrl) {
        absoluteRestUrl = config.adminRestEndpoint; // defaultUrl
    }
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let res = null;
        res = await $.post(absoluteRestUrl, param, null, 'json');
        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a promise when jQuery's Ajax basically already does it?

Comment: @epascarello , I made it this way when I need to manipulate/process jQuery response before resolving the result